# Calculating camera near and far distance based on bounding box

Tags: three.js

I want to calculate the camera near and far distance based on an axis aligned bounding box using three.js.
I tried this way:

```
getNearFar = function(camera, box) {
    var view_matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    view_matrix.copy( camera.matrixWorldInverse.getInverse( camera.matrixWorld ) );
    var minz = +Infinity; var maxz = -Infinity;

    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var x = i & 1 ? box.min.x : box.max.x;
        var y = i & 2 ? box.min.y : box.max.y;
        var z = i & 4 ? box.min.z : box.max.z;
        var p =  new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
        p.applyMatrix3(view_matrix);
        z = -p.z;
        if (z > maxz) maxz = z;
        if (z < minz) minz = z;
    }

    return {'near':minz, 'far':maxz};
};
```

What I did is to get the camera view matrix, and convert the 8 corner points of the box into camera space. The near and far distance should be the min and max z. But it does not give the correct answer. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found out what's wrong:
it should be p.applyMatrix4()